# Flow property of a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

In order to solve this question I must fix $s$ while allowing $t$ to vary. I am confused as to why this is allowed.

Answer (score 2):

Show $\phi_{t-s}(y)$ is a solution to $x'(t)=f(x(t))$, $x(s)=y$.

The set $y=ϕ_s(x)$ and do some arithmetic manipulations of the time index.

---

The task proper is to compare two solutions of the ODE, one to an unspecified IVP $x_1'=f(x_1)$ $x_1(0)=x_0$ and one to the dependent IVP $x_2'=f(x_2)$, $x_2(s)=x_1(s)$. Now argue that $x_1=x_2$ everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to show that both $t \mapsto \phi_{t+s}(x)$ and $t \mapsto \phi_t(\phi_s(x))$ satisfy the same initial value problem, $$\dot{x}=f(x),\ \ x(0)=\phi_s(x).$$ Because $f$ is continuously differentiable, the existence and uniqueness theorem tells you that both solutions agree. In addition, one should be careful about the time interval on which the solution exists.